# How can I style WebVTT Closed Captions in Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

Has anyone had any success styling WebVTT closed captions in the IE10/11 HTML5 video element?

I can style the captions using the ::cue CSS selector in Safari/Chrome/FF etc. BUT it appears to have no effect on the same element in IE.

The default IE caption style is to have white text with a tiny black text shadow behind it (not the most visible on some colors) but I want it to have a gray slightly transparent background behind the text like the other browsers.

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: Sam, please share if you've get success adding background on captions :)

Comment: Hey @KunJ웃 - annoyingly, I did not have any success restyling the captions UI in IE10/11. You can do it in a lot of other browsers using the :cue selector though.....

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed this site? 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mediastuff/2014/03/05/closed-captioning-its-not-just-for-accessibility-texttrack-in-html5-video/

It talks about adding a track id element in your html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Simple track example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video id="video1" controls autoplay>
      <source src="http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Videos/BehindIE9ModernWebStandards/Video.mp4"  >
      <track id='track1' label='English captions' src="entrack.vtt" kind='subtitles' srclang='en' default >   
    </video>

  </body>
</html>
```